# weak convergence to almost sure convergence in the Skorokhod theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

On $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$ ($B(\mathbb{R})$ : Borel sets), consider
$X$ to be a random variable normally distributed with zero mean and unit variance.

Let $Y_n=(-1)^nX$.

For any neglectible set $N$, it is clear that $Y_n(w)\nrightarrow X(w)$ for any $w\in N$ so we do not have almost sure convergence of $Y_n$ to $X$ but we have the convergence in distribution since $F_{Y_n}=F_X$ where $F_G$ denotes the cumulative probability distribution of a random variable $G$.

I would like now to construct a sequence $Z_n$ of random variable so that the condition of the Skorokhod representation theorem is satisfied :

- $Z_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same law
- $Z_n \to X$ almost surely

If I define $Z_n(w) = X(w)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ then it seems the two conditions above are satisfied because again $F_{Z_n}=F_{X}=F_{Y_n}$ and the second condition is trivial.